# How do I drill a hole flush (or nearly flush) against another surface?

Tags: tools, drill

How do I drill a hole flush (or nearly flush) against another surface? (eg. in a tight corner; a 90 degree angle.) The power drill bit is offset a little by design, and I don't want to drill at an angle. What kind of tool or attachment should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [flexible shaft bit holder](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ryobi-11-in-Flexible-Shaft-Bit-Holder-A10FB1G/205193137)

[image: flexible shaft]

It easily bends to 90 degrees, is designed to be used with hex shaft bits and takes up less room than a 3/4 inch bit.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of products/sources.
```

Comment: This is perfect. It's thin enough, versatile, and not costly. Thanks!

Comment: If you read the documentation for some of these, they recommend you not use them drilling. Drilling often involves higher RPMs, which these units are not designed to handle (especially when bent at tight angles).

Comment: @Tester101 I agree that they are not great for high speed drilling.  The bit does not lock into the shaft's collet, just held by the hex shape and a magnet. But for slower speeds they work pretty well. And you often need just a little bend to get the drill bit close to the wall.

Comment: Might be true of other brands, but not the item linked above. It comes with no instructions and there are no rules about power drill use on the packaging. I even bought compatible drill bits from the same company.

Comment: A small caution - if you are drilling deeply, keep backing the bit out to clear the waste and keep the bit running freely. If you do not, you can end up with a bit buried and stuck in the wood that the magnet can't extract.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a 90 degree drill bit adapter.

[image]